# How to use same screen for different tabs based on states

Tags: react-native

I have two tabs Tab1 and Tab2 both tabs will have same screen so I have created one screen but it will show the data based on states like I have 4 states i.e "new", "processing", "success", "failure". Now I want to show only "new" and "processing" states data in Tab1 and "success" and "failure" in Tabs. Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could hava a parent component which passes down the required props to the Tab Screen:

```
const TabItem = ({new, processing, success, failure}) => {
  

  //do stuff here depending on if new, processing, success or failure
  return <View />
}

const TabContainer = () => {


  return (
   <View>
     <TabItem new={"New stuff"} processing="Processing stuff" />
     <TabItem success={"Success stuff"} failure="Failure stuff" />
   </View>
  )
}
```